# How does lexical analyzer remove white spaces from source file?

Tags: compilers, lexical-analysis

In compiler at phase lexical analyzer, how does lexical analyze strip out white spaces from source file?.

Comment: It just ignores it. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: It's a finite automaton. Go figure.

Comment: This question seems to have an answer in *any* resource on lexers. What research have you done? What did you not understand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A brief answer is "by ignoring them".
A compiler may scan the entire code more than once, but of course at least once in which case we call it a *single-pass* compiler. The task of lexical analyzer (or sometimes called simply *scanner*) is to generate tokens. This is done simply by scanning the entire code (in linear manner by loading it for example into an array) from the beginning to the end symbol-by-symbol and grouping them into tokens. Thus, while checking each symbol (of the source code) you just skip the white-space symbols. Similarly you skip comments in the source code.

As to my personal experience, I had to implement a single-pass compiler for a made-up simple language which allowed both white space symbols (TAB, NEW-LINE, SPACE) and comments. I loaded the entire source code into a linear array and as my lexical analyzer went over the code character by character it simply skipped all white space symbols and comments by moving forward the pointer pointing to the current character.

But depending on the implementation you could first pass over the source code just to remove all white spaces, and then on the second pass generate tokens.

**Caution:**  "ignoring whitespace" shouldn't be interpreted as "remove all white space symbols from the source and then further process the source code". In some cases depending on the language construct white spaces may indicate when a token ends for example in the following piece of code

```
  int foo(int x)
  {
    return x+2;
  }
```

The tokens TYPE (int) and the IDENTIFIER (foo) are separated by a single SPACE. But the IDENTIFIER (foo) and immediate LEFTPAR are not separated by any white space symbol.

Also (on Derek Elkins' comment) real compilers usually use whitespace for producing clear error messages, for example for keeping track of line numbers.

Comment: Nitpick: "ignoring whitespace" could be read as if the lexer would yield the same result on the input string if all whitespace was removed. That's typically not the case: whitespace *is* used to detect were tokens end. "Ignore" here means that whitespace is not translated into tokens by itself.

Comment: @Raphael we do **not always** use white-spaces to detect end of tokens and in general white spaces do not indicate where token ends. That's not the case.  Consider the following piece of code `a=123;`. We have the following tokens: IDENTIFIER, EQUAL, INT, SEMICOLON. The first three tokens are not separated by any whitespace symbol. Though there are cases when two tokens are separated by white spaces, for example `void int func(int x)...`.

Comment: Yes. The *general* rule is that the set of token classes must form a prefix-free set, roughly speaking. (Precedence rules, reserved keywords, etc muddle the situation.) Whitespace (as something that is not part of *any* token) is a useful *option* to effect this, and weeaken the rule somewhat. In fact,  I can't think of many languages that make do completely without whitespace.

Comment: @raphael: FORTRAN.

Comment: @rici Was that the language where putting spaces in float literals would yield valid code (that exploded space rockets)?

Comment: @Raphael yes, Mariner 1, but error was period in place of a comma

Comment: @fade2black: maybe, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_1#Overbar_transcription_error (as that article says later on, "there is no evidence that FORTRAN was used in the mission".)

Comment: Raphael: I don't know how to interpret "roughly speaking" in that comment, but to a first approximation there is no requirement at all that token classes be prefix-free, and very few languages (if any) manage that. Practically all token sets will include tokens which are suffixes of tokens in other sets: `==` vs. `=`; `forest` vs. `for`. Numbers are practically the only exception. The normal rule is "maximal munch", which explicitly allows sets without the prefix property. But even that rule is occasionally circumvented. (`3..4` is a range in some languages, for example. Or `<::`in C++.)

Comment: It should be noted that *real* compilers usually do *not* ignore whitespace as it is usually important for producing clear error messages.

Comment: @DerekElkins thanks. Right. But when it comes to generating tokens, creating parse trees, and later translating into machine code the white space symbols are really ignored. Nevertheless, I'll edit and add your comment to avoid confusions.

Comment: @fade2black thank you for the long explanation.now I know the answer to my question.

Comment: @fade2black buddy, i got stuck into another question **different translators required for converting a high-level language to an executable code.**     i studied the whole language processing system in compiler book __Addison Wesley - Aho, Sethi, Ullman Compilers Principles, Techinques, And Tools__ in first chapter.  but i didn't figure out.could u help me with that??.

Comment: What kind of help do you want? My experience does not go beyond generating of intermediate code. I have never implemented compiler translating into real code. But I could recommend you follow [this  tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html) if you have enough theoretical knowledge. Also, if you want to implement a compiler simply for educational purpose then I think you do not need to go that deep into code generation. It is enough, for example, to generate for JVM (which is platform independent).

Comment: @fade2black thanks for your quick responce. i dont wanna implement compiler or construct compiler i just wanna know the answer of this question _different translators required for converting a high-level language to an executable code??_ and i don't need to generate code. its just the question which has been given to me in assignment. i tried to find the answer but i think i cant.

Comment: @fade2black, how will you tokenize a+++b ? I think it will be a++ + b because of greedy scanning. Now if it would have been a + ++b then it will be interpreted as a + ++b which is quite different. So white space plays a role I guess.

Comment: @Zephyr I guess this is the same as what operation in $2*3+1$ we should perform first:  multiplication or or addition. We usually first do multiplication then addition. In other words, we resolve this disambiguity by introducing *operator precedence*. So the answer to your question depends on a language design  and its implementation. In C/C++ I guess it would be first `a++` and then addition as you suggest. Just try and see how it is evaluated in C/C++.