# Conflicts in LR(0) parser

Tags: compilers

Why don't we consider conflicts caused due to augmented production?

[image]

This picture shows the states of a LR(0) parser.

In the above picture, why we don't consider shift reduce conflict at state I2 ? Shift on '+' and reduce on E'->E. (Augmented production).

Also what is the need of augmented production at the beginning ?

Comment: What is the context here? Is the task possibly to find the conflict? Does the parser have access to the FOLLOW sets? This diagram seems to missing multiple things; it doesn't seem to represent a full parser at once. Where did you get the image?

Comment: I have mentioned it as LR(0) parser so there is no need of follow sets. I0 state contains all the initial productions in the grammar. I don't understand what is missing here.

Comment: Someone please help.